# Append a new subnet to existing VNet

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am working on adding a subnet to an existing subnet but I am having trouble with overlapping ID.

I have a subnet module that will be created for every function app that I provision.

I am trying to append a subnet to an existing VNET dedicated for every new function app that is being created. However, I am having problems as I am encountering an overlapping subnets.

In my `address_prefixes` of the subnet, I have,

cidrsubnet((data.azurerm_virtual_network.existing_vnet[0].address_space)[0], var.subnet_size,[Number of subnet list in vnet] )

I need the netnum of to be the next available index of the subnet

Comment: please share the code you tried @eojilaJA

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to Append a new subnet to existing VNet using terraform and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

If you want to use Terraform to add a new subnet to a VNet for every function app, you have to avoid overlapping subnet problems. To do this, you have to plan your CIDR blocks well and make sure that each subnet has a different address space that does not conflict with any other subnets in the VNet.

To calculate non-overlapping CIDR blocks for each subnet within the existing VNet's address space, we can use the `cidrsubnet` function. This function takes three parameters: an IP network address, a new network bit length (subnet mask), and a network number. It returns a new subnet address based on these parameters. The challenge is to dynamically assign a unique `netnum` value to each subnet so that they do not overlap with each other in the VNet's address space.

To overcome the issue, I tried a terraform configuration.

**Terraform configuration: **

**main.tf:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "existing" {
  name = var.resource_group_name
}

data "azurerm_virtual_network" "existing_vnet" {
  name                = var.vnet_name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "function_app_subnet" {
  count                = length(var.function_apps)
  name                 = "${var.function_apps[count.index].name}-subnet"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.existing.name
  virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_virtual_network.existing_vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = [cidrsubnet(data.azurerm_virtual_network.existing_vnet.address_space[0], 8, count.index + 3)] # Adjusted newbits and netnum
}  


resource "azurerm_service_plan" "plan" {
  count               = length(var.function_apps)
  name                = "${var.function_apps[count.index].name}-asp"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.existing.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.existing.name
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "P1v2"
 
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storage" {
  count               = length(var.function_apps)
  name                = "st${format("%03d", count.index)}${substr(md5(var.function_apps[count.index].name), 0, 8)}"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.existing.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.existing.location
  account_tier        = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "function_app" {
  count               = length(var.function_apps)
  name                = var.function_apps[count.index].name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.existing.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.existing.location
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.plan[count.index].id
  storage_account_name     = azurerm_storage_account.storage[count.index].name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.storage[count.index].primary_access_key

  app_settings = {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME" = "dotnet"
    // Add other necessary app settings here
  }

  site_config {
    // Add site configuration here
  }
}
```

**variable.tf:**

```
variable "resource_group_name" {
  description = "Name of the existing resource group"
  type        = string
}

variable "vnet_name" {
  description = "Name of the existing virtual network"
  type        = string
}

variable "subnet_prefix_length" {
  description = "The desired subnet prefix length"
  type        = number
}

variable "function_apps" {
  description = "List of function app configurations"
  type = list(object({
    name = string
    // You can add other properties here as needed for each function app
  }))
}
```

**terraform.tfvars:**

```
resource_group_name  = "demovksb-rg"
vnet_name            = "testvkvnet"
subnet_prefix_length = 24
function_apps        = [
  { name = "funcvkapp1" },
  { name = "funcvkapp2" },
  // Add more function apps as needed
]
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]